# Decide baseclass at runtime

Tags: python, oop, class

I want to do something like this:

```
class A:

    def methodA(self):
        return 5

class B:
    def methodB(self):
        return 10

class X(...):

    def __init__(self, baseclass):
        if baseclass =='A' : derive X from A
        elif baseclass == 'B' : derive X from B
        else: raise Exception("Not supported baseclass %s!" % (baseclass))

    def methodX(self):
        return 42

X('A').methodA() # returns 5
X('A').methodX() # returns 42
X('A').methodB() # methodB not defined
X('B').methodB() # returns 10
X('B').methodX() # returns 42
X('A').methodA() # methodA not defined
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add `methodX` to the existing classes, you could consider multiple inheritance:

```
class A:
    def methodA(self):
        return 5

class B:
    def methodB(self):
        return 10

class X():
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, baseclass):
        if baseclass == A:
            return AX()
        elif baseclass == B:
            return BX()
        else: raise Exception("Not supported baseclass %s!" % str(baseclass))

    def methodX(self):
        return 42

class AX(A, X):
    pass

class BX(B, X):
    pass
```

You can add args and kwargs to `X.new` and pass them on to the specific constructors.  Here are the outputs of your tests (I corrected the last on in your question):

```
>>> ax = X.new(A)
>>> ax.methodA() # returns 5
5
>>> ax.methodX() # returns 42
42
>>> ax.methodB() # methodB not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: AX instance has no attribute 'methodB'
>>> bx = X.new(B)
>>> bx.methodB() # returns 10
10
>>> bx.new(B).methodX() # returns 42
42
>>> bx.new(B).methodA() # methodA not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: BX instance has no attribute 'methodA'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need. I have never before felt the need to use `@classmethod`, but this is a very useful example. A little note: in the general case, for `AX` both `A.__init__` and `X.__init__` must be called.

Answer (score 2):

You should define two classes, `X` and `Y`, and a factory-method to instantiate either X or Y, depending on a parameter.

In general, the behavior you try to implement is somewhat confusing. When you create an instance (that is what `X(...)` does) you should get an instance of `X`, and instances of a class should have same attributes. That is one of the main reasons why classes exist.

Example:

```
class A:
    def methodA(self):
        return 5

class B:
    def methodB(self):
        return 10

def x(class_name):
    name2class = {"A":A, "B":B}
    return name2class[class_name]()

for name in ["A","B","C"]:
    instance = x(name)
    print name, instance
```

will print

```
A <__main__.A instance at 0x022C8D50>
B <__main__.B instance at 0x022C8DF0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../14834949.py", line 21, in <module>
    instance = x(name)
  File ".../14834949.py", line 18, in x
    return name2class[class_name]()
KeyError: 'C'
```

Comment: Mmmm. Not so easy. My class X extends the baseclass with some common functionality, which I do not want to duplicate. Please, see my edited question.

Comment: To give you some background: I want to extend some classes (`graph` and `digraph`, from `pygraph`) with extra functionality. But I can not change the way those classes are defined (I can not modify their baseclass, which would be the ideal solution), since they belong to a third-party library. I want to add funtionality which will be common to both `graph` and `digraph`.